# Validation for dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, validation, html-select, dropdown

This is my first post here, so please no penalty points for me if there is anything unclear with my question. If so, I will edit or add necessary info.

I have an assignment for creating javascript validation method for html input and select, that validates both fields and removes error message after entering details or selecting drop-down option. And, I am having a problem with the second part which I do not seem to be able to find a solution for, and precisely:
1) **error message does not disappear when an option from select is chosen** (it works for input)

I was trying few things but obviously I do not see my mistakes and I really hope someone could point me in the right direction here.

**And here is the code for validation:**

```
        var validations = {
        req: function(data){
            return (data != '' && data.length > 0);
        }   
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function addError(fname, error){
            $('[name=' + fname + ']').after('<span class="validationError"> ' + error + '</span>');
        }
        function removeError(fname){
            $('[name=' + fname + ']').parent('div').find('.validationError').remove();
        }
        var map = {};
        for(var x in validationRules){
            var fname = validationRules[x][0];
            if(typeof fname == 'undefined') continue;
            if(typeof map[fname] == 'undefined') map[fname] = [];
            map[fname].push({
                'method' : validationRules[x][1],
                'error' : validationRules[x][2]
            });
        };
        for(var x in map){
            $('[name=' + x + ']').on('keyup', function(){           
                var fname = $(this).attr('name'),
                    validators = map[fname];
                removeError(fname);             
                for(var y in validators){
                    if(typeof validators[y] == 'function') continue;                
                    if(!validations[validators[y].method]($(this).val())) addError(fname, validators[y].error);
                }
            });
        }
        $('#send, #insert').on('click', function(ev){       
            var isOk = true;
            $('.validationError').remove();         
            for(var x in map){
                for(var y in map[x]){
                    if(typeof map[x][y] == 'function' || !$('[name=' + x + ']').is(':visible')) continue;

                    if(!validations[map[x][y].method]($('[name=' + x + ']').val())){
                        addError(x, map[x][y].error);
                        isOk = false;
                    }
                }
            };
            return isOk;
        });
    });
```

**and html form:**

```
    <form action="form-handler.php" method="post" class="form-contacts">
    <div class="row col-sm-12 form-break1">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-3 form-label">Your name</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
            <input class="textInput" type="text" name="Name" value="" placeholder="Name & Surname" maxlength="50" />    
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="row col-sm-12 form-break1">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-3 form-label">Vehicle Make </div>       
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
            <select name="Vehicle">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="Vehicle 1">Vehicle 1</option>
                <option value="Vehicle 2">Vehicle 2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>                                  
    <div class="wrapper sendButtons">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-3"><input id="send" type="submit" value="Send Request"></div>
    </div>                                          
</form>
```

And finally, just before closing body tag,  **validation rules**

```
<script>
    var validationRules = [
        // section 1
        ["Name","req","Please enter your full name & surname"],
        ["Vehicle","req","Select Vehicle"]
    ]   
</script>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and insert your code into a Code Snippet (on the edit toolbar) so that it can be run and easily copied into an executable answer.

Comment: Actually - please disregard this. 10 min after I sent a post a solution struck me and it is working now.

Comment: Then please update your question to include your solution. This site is a knowledge base for others who come along in the future.